How Does Irodov Derive This?

Potential and strength of the field of a point dipole with electric moment $\mathbf{p}$:
$$\varphi=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\,\frac{\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{r}}{r^3},\quad E=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{p}{r^3}\sqrt{1+3\cos^2\theta}.\tag{3.1d}$$

The formula for the potential due to a point dipole (shown on the left) is well-established. To determine a formula for the electric field due to a dipole, I attempted to take the gradient of the potential. However, I cannot seem to simplify my answer to obtain the formula that is shown on the right. Any assistance is appreciated.
